# Executar o próximo passo sem passar por um anterior a esse

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte problema, se o usuário não digitar nem 'S' ou 'N' irá retorna a mensagem de erro que tratei, no entanto irá continuar o loop, mais eu queria uma forma de não pedir novamente pra digitar o número novamente e se digitar a resposta da variável 'pergunta'.

```
def caractere(resposta):
    # false
    if resposta == 'N':
        return 'Encerrando programa...'

    # true
    elif resposta == 'S': 
        return 'Ok, vamos continuar...'

    # true
    elif resposta not in 'SN':
        return 'Caractere inválido. Digite novamente'



def main():
    while True:
        try:
            numero = float(input('Digite um número: '))
            print(f'O cubo do numero {numero} é igual {numero ** 3}')
            pergunta = str(input('Deseja continuar[sim - S/não - N]: ')).upper()[0]
            resultado = caractere(pergunta)
            
            if pergunta == 'S':
                print(resultado)

            elif pergunta == 'N':
                print(resultado)
                break
            
            elif pergunta not in 'SN':
                print(resultado)

        except:
            print('Valor inválido, tente novamente.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def caractere(resposta):
    # false
    if resposta == 'N':
        return 'Encerrando programa...'

    # true
    elif resposta == 'S': 
        return 'Ok, vamos continuar...'

    # true
    elif resposta not in 'SN':
        return 'Caractere inválido. Digite novamente'

def continuar():
    pergunta = ""
    while (pergunta == "S" or pergunta == "N") == False:
        pergunta = str(input('Deseja continuar[sim - S/não - N]: ')).upper()[0]
        print(caractere(pergunta))

    return pergunta

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            numero = float(input('Digite um número: '))
            print(f'O cubo do numero {numero} é igual {numero ** 3}')
            pergunta = continuar()
            
            if pergunta == "N":
                break

        except:
            print('Valor inválido, tente novamente.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```